# Как добавлять данные в QTableWidget и записать в БД sqlite3?

Tags: python, pyqt5, sqlite3, qlistwidget, qtsql

Добавляю данные в таблицу, но при вводе новых данных на нового человека старые стираются, а новые появляются.

Как сделать так, чтобы данные добавлялись в ряд дальше? 
Всю голову сломал уже в отчаянии, help

Вот код:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import sqlite3
import sys


conn = sqlite3.connect('todo.db')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE if not exists disp_list(disp_name text, disp_surname text, disp_date text)')
conn.commit()
conn.close()


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(960, 550)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(610, 261, 341, 241))
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(610, 180, 331, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 311, 41))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(340, 40, 311, 41))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(690, 40, 251, 41))
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget, clicked=lambda: self.add_disp())
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 100, 221, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 100, 221, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton_3.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(720, 100, 221, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton_4.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 200, 591, 301))
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(130)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(3)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(18)
        item.setFont(font)
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(180)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 291, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial Black")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 10, 291, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial Black")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(690, 10, 251, 20))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial Black")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(510, 100, 191, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton_5.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 960, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def add_disp(self):
        name = self.lineEdit.text()
        surname = self.lineEdit_2.text()
        date = self.lineEdit_3.text()
        disps=[{"disp_name": name, "disp_surname": surname, "disp_date":  date}]
        for person in disps:
            row = 1
            self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(person["disp_name"]))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(person["disp_surname"]))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 2, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(person["disp_date"]))
        name = self.lineEdit.setText("")
        surname = self.lineEdit_2.setText("")
        date = self.lineEdit_3.setText("")

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Список диспетчеров, у которых заканчивается срок"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Add ATC"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Delete from table"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Delete from database"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Name"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Surname"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Issue_date"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Enter name"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Enter surname"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Enter date"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Save to database"))






if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: `for person in disps: row = 1` <- всегда 1

Comment: Да, это типа ряд в который всегда будет добавляться инфа. Все перерыл, никак не могу сделать чтобы не только в этот ряд, но и и дальше шло как бы. Не подскажете как? Может код. Вы спасете меня(((

Comment: Вам нужен метод `QTableWidget.insertRow()`  вот пример https://stackoverflow.com/a/24057575/4711135

Comment: Даже если уже задано количество row = 130? У меня в коде выше там есть. Или убрать указание количества рядов?

Comment: Нет, если задано, то просто пробегаетесь в цикле по строкам и вставляете данные

Comment: Александр не подскажете как это сделать? Перелопатил и это тоже но чо т не получается запустить адекватно без крашей. Я так понял нужно сделать итерацию через все ряды?

Comment: Да, пробегаетесь по нужным строкам и вставляете данные. Сейчас вы всегда вставляете в строку с индексом 1

Comment: А какой код здесь использовать? Помогите пожалуйста. For row in range я так понимаю, а дальше, ведь у меня там еще 'disp' еще, как это все воедино закодить?

Comment: вы спрашиваете, как добавлять данные в QListWidget? Но я вижу только ваши попытки записывать строку с данными в QTableWidget. Что вы хотите добавить  в QListWidget? Объясните лучше.

Comment: В приложении будет возможность считать имя фамилию и дату с lineedit и их вставить в таблицу. после того как таблицу заполнили можно будет сохранить это в базу и т.д я когда добавляю в таблицу то добавляется только в первую строку, а если дальше пытаюсь вбить данные то они перезаписывают предуыдущие данные в таблице, а мне надо чтоб дальше в таблицу записывалось, заполняя ее, а не только вставляя в перый ряд, перезаписывая предыдущую инфу

Comment: stan_88, т.е. в QListWidget пока ничего добавлять не надо? Вам нужна помощь с добавлением в QTableWidget? Если так, то внесите изменения в заголовок вопроса и добавьте все что вы написали в комментариях в тело вопроса.

Comment: Блин извините пожалуйста, qtablewidget конечно же, просто голова уже не варит(( Добавлять в таблицу qtablewidget , да

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**НИКОГДА НЕ ИЗМЕНЯЙТЕ** код, сгенерированный Qt Designer, **НИКОГДА**. 
Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

---

[**Qt SQL**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtsql-index.html) — это важный модуль, обеспечивающий поддержку баз данных `SQL`.

Руководство по программированию на  [**SQL Programming**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-programming.ht) содержит информацию о разработке с использованием `Qt SQL`.

Обратите внимание, что я заменил виджет `QTableWidget` на [**QTableView**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html) 
Класс `QTableView` предоставляет реализацию model/view
по умолчанию для табличного представления.

Обратите внимание, что я добавил свой диалог для ввода данных.

Я также немного прокомментировал код для вас, попробуйте.

```
import sys
#import sqlite3
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlQuery, QSqlTableModel, QSqlQueryModel # +++
from PyQt5.Qt import *

# !!!
''' я предполагаю что todo.db у вас уже создана                                 # !!!
conn = sqlite3.connect('todo.db')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE if not exists disp_list(
    disp_name text, disp_surname text, disp_date text)')
conn.commit()
conn.close()
'''

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(960, 550)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(610, 261, 341, 241))
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(610, 180, 331, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 311, 41))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(340, 40, 311, 41))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(690, 40, 251, 41))
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        
#        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget, clicked=lambda: self.add_disp())
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 100, 221, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 100, 221, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton_3.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(720, 100, 221, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton_4.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")

#        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableView(self.centralwidget)
                
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 200, 591, 301))
#        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(130)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
#        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(3)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(18)
        item.setFont(font)
        
#        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
#        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
#        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
#        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(180)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 291, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial Black")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 10, 291, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial Black")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(690, 10, 251, 20))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial Black")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(510, 100, 191, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton_5.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 960, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)


    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Список диспетчеров, у которых заканчивается срок"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Add ATC"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Delete from table"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Delete from database"))
#        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
#        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Name"))
#        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
#        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Surname"))
#        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
#        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Issue_date"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Enter name"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Enter surname"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Enter date"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Save to database"))


class Dialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Input Dialog')

        self.line_edit_name = QLineEdit()
        self.line_edit_surname = QLineEdit()
        self.line_edit_date = QLineEdit()

        form_layout = QFormLayout()
        form_layout.addRow('Name:', self.line_edit_name)
        form_layout.addRow('Surname:', self.line_edit_surname)
        form_layout.addRow('Date:', self.line_edit_date)

        button_box = QDialogButtonBox(QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)
        button_box.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        button_box.rejected.connect(self.reject)

        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addLayout(form_layout)
        main_layout.addWidget(button_box)
        self.setLayout(main_layout)
        

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.add_disp) 
        
        # 1. Создайте соединение с базой данных, вызвав метод addDatabase() класса QSqlDatabase. 
        #    Так как вы хотите соединиться с базой данных SQLite, параметры QSQLITE передаются здесь. 
        db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')  
        
        # 2. Вызовите setDatabaseName(), чтобы установить имя базы данных, которое будет использоваться.
        #    Вам нужно только написать путь, а имя файла заканчивается на .db 
        #   (если база данных уже существует, используйте базу данных; если она не существует,
        #    будет создана новая);         
        db.setDatabaseName('todo.db')         
        
        # 3. Вызовите метод open(), чтобы открыть базу данных.
        #    Если открытие прошло успешно, оно вернет True, а в случае неудачи - False. 
        db.open()

        # Создайте модель QSqlTableModel и вызовите setTable(), 
        # чтобы выбрать таблицу данных для обработки.      
        self.model = QSqlTableModel(self)
        self.model.setTable("disp_list")           # !!! тавлица в db
        
        # вызовите метод select(), чтобы выбрать все данные в таблице, и соответствующее
        # представление также отобразит все данные;
        self.model.select()
        self.tableWidget.setModel(self.model)        

    def add_disp(self):
        inputDialog = Dialog()
        rez = inputDialog.exec()
        if not rez:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Внимание', 'Диалог сброшен.')
            return  
        name = inputDialog.line_edit_name.text()
        surname = inputDialog.line_edit_surname.text()
        date = inputDialog.line_edit_date.text()
        if not name or not surname or not date:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Внимание', 'Заполните пожалуйста все поля.')
            return             
    
        r = self.model.record()
        r.setValue("disp_name", name)
        r.setValue("disp_surname", surname)
        r.setValue("disp_date", date)
        self.model.insertRecord(-1, r)
        self.model.select()    
         

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо огромное! буду пробовать