# Как осуществить выбор режима для таблицы SQLite3?

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite3

Хотелось бы узнать есть ли какие-то способы и виджеты ткинтер, которые позволяют выводить на экране данные из БД? А также, как можно осуществить переключение режимов работы с таблицей, например щёлкаю ПКМ в любом месте окна и вылезает контекстное меню с выбором режима(чтение, редактирование, добавление, удаление данных). Если можно, то приведите пример, хотя бы из одной строчки таблицы.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1413887 , https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1372411 , https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1373113 , ...